# ¿Por qué recibo el error "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"?

Tags: python

```
import random 

res = imput("Desea lanzar los dados: S/N")
while(res == 'S') 

       n1 = random.randint(1,6) 
       n2 = random.randint(1,6) 

       print("El dado uno cayo en:" + str(n1)  +  y el dado dos en:" + str(n2)) 
       print("La suma de los dos dados lanzado es: " + str(n1 + n2) + "\n") 

       res = imput("Desea lanzar los dados: S/N ")
```

terminal me sale

```
beatriz@beatriz-Lenovo:~/Escritorio/python-course$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py
  File "/home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py", line 5
    
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
beatriz@beatriz-Lenovo:~/Escritorio/python-course$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py
  File "/home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py", line 5
    
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
beatriz@beatriz-Lenovo:~/Escritorio/python-course$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py
  File "/home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py", line 5
    
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
beatriz@beatriz-Lenovo:~/Escritorio/python-course$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py
  File "/home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py", line 4
    while(res =='S')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
beatriz@beatriz-Lenovo:~/Escritorio/python-course$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py
  File "/home/beatriz/Escritorio/python-course/tiradas_de_dados.py", line 5
    
                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: voto para cerrar como error tipográfico

Answer (score 2):

Falta un ":" en

```
while(res == 'S')
```

Lo correcto es

```
while(res == 'S'):
```

Recuerda que el ":" siempre marca el comienzo de un bloque de instrucciones ejecutadas condicionalmente (if, for, ...).

Answer (score 1):

**Correcciones:**

Tal como dice @Candid Moe, hay que añadir `:` al final del `while` *(+1 up)*

Además, faltará también una `"` en `+ " y el dado dos en:"`
y sustituir los 2 `imput` por `input`

Espero que sea útil ;)

Comment: donde pongo las """ el resto modifique : y la n en vez d m de input

Comment: Falta en `str(n1)  +  y el dado dos en:"` que debería ser `str(n1)  +  "y el dado dos en:"`